# Blender supported 3D files that support armature

Tags: texturing, rigging, armature, bones, file-format

I am just doing some research for an interactive app where I need some 3D assets. I dont have enoguh time to model all myself, so I have to use already existing assets. Since I dont have 3D Max, Cinema 4d or Maya, I have to use Blender for editing and adding further animations to my assets.

My Problem is, most assets I found so far are .3ds files, .obj or fbx.

**My Question is: What 3D file formats support bones?**

I want to use assets that are already rigged, so I dont have to rig and texture everything again.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities depending on the tools used:

1. Use OBJ files in combination with BVH. BVH contains the skeleton,
   and OBJ is capable of containing vertex weights
2. DAE which is one file that can contain both the weights and the
       skeleton. This is the best format IMO and is widely supported
       (although perhaps slightly less supported than OBJ/BHV).

If FBX is your only option, I've used a program that converts FBX to DAE.

http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/item?siteID=123112&id=20481519